# Updating ADO.Net Entity Data Model programmatically

Tags: c#, ado.net, entity, datamodel

We want to update a ADO.Net Entity Data Model programmatically, so that the EDM is getting the newest version of the database (new tables, values etc.). I want to have a complete update of all stuff.

I know that it is possible to update the EDM, by clicking in the Model Designer, Update Model from Database.

Do you know any solution?

Thank you in advance.